# Laravel 5 weird error?

Tags: laravel-5

I copied all the source code of the project (Laravel 5) to another folder under htdocs folder.

The original project is running successfully.

But the destination project has this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145
in RouteCollection.php line 145
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 716
.....
```

Please help me figure it out.

Sorry about my English.

Comment: Looks like the url structure changes when you moved the folder?

Comment: if you are using vagrant and homestead, it looks like path problem in Homestead.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar problem today, Although I don't know if there are better solutions out there. However, I had to re-install laravel5 with composer using the following command.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel newprojectname --prefer-dist
```

One more thing, I also noticed that I was typing the directory location to my laravel project differently from the way I saved it locally on my development windows PC. That is I was accessing the file location like so

```
http://localhost/laravel/projectdirectoryname
```

instead of something like this:

```
http://localhost/laravel/ProjectDirectoryName/
```

In summary, I named my project directory on my local drive, in camel-case (upper-lowercase), like so; `ProjectDirectoryName` while, I was accessing the project in the browser, in all lowercase, like so; `projectdirectoryname`. Although, this may not be applicable on a linux-dev machine, because of its case-sensitive constrain. However, this is possible in a windows-dev machine